# Java приложение справочник пород собак

Tags: java, javafx

Всем привет нужна помощь. Суть вопроса проста, пишу курсовую работу вроде как согласовал с руководителем, что можно написать на WPF и в принципе проблем бы не было, но теперь все резко изменилось нужно писать на Java... Я в Java полный 0 смог сделать только кнопочки (на фото) сейчас дизайн не главное) Так вот, как реализовать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с названием породы в центре выводился текст с описанием породы и т.д ? Сроки поджимают если несложно хелпаните буду рад любой помощи. Заранее спасибо.
(P.S)
Пишу в IntelliJ IDEA с JavaFX первое, что нашел)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть эта ссылка поможет https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2560-vvedenie-v-java-fx

Comment: Вам нужно повесить на кнопку onAction через SceneBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Если вам принципиально написать это приложение на JavaFX, рекомендую посмотреть для начала на youtube простые уроки (по запросу "создание приложения на javafx").

Либо можете этот же проект реализовать на классической библиотеке Swing  без использования JavaFX.

Пример простого оконного приложения на Swing, в котором создана одна кнопка и одно текстовое поле, в которое при нажатии на кнопку вставляется описание.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SimpleFrameClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //объявление кнопки
    JButton button1;

    //объявление textArea
    JTextArea textArea;
    
    //создание конструктора окна
    SimpleFrameClass() {
        
        setTitle("My window");
        
        setSize(400, 250);
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        //создание кнопки и добавление ее на JFrame
        button1 = new JButton("button № 1");    
        button1.setBounds(100, 50, 200, 30);
        this.add(button1);
        
        //прикрепление ActionListener к кнопке
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        
        //создание textArea и добавление его на JFrame  
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 100);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        this.add(textArea);
        
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //запуск программы в методе main
        new SimpleFrameClass();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        //если при нажатии мыши выбрана кнопка № 1, вставить в 
        //текстовое поле текст из переменной s
        if(e.getSource()==button1){
            String s = "set some text in the textArea after clicking button # 1";
            textArea.setText(s);
        }
        
        /*аналогично для других кнопок 
        if(e.getSource()==button2){
            .............
        }
        if(e.getSource()==button3){
            .............
        }
        if(e.getSource()==button4){
            .............
        }
        */  
    }
}
```